# encodeURIComponent algorithm source code

Tags: javascript, encoding, titanium

I am developing an application in titanium using Javascript. I need an open source implementation of `encodeURIComponent` in Javascript.

Can anybody guide me or show me some implementation?

Comment: You can find Mozilla's implementation of `str_encodeURI_Component` in "/js/src/jsstr.cpp": [http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/src/jsstr.cpp](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/src/jsstr.cpp) or [http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/).

Comment: @XP1 Mozilla has retired MXR; that page is now at https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/src/jsstr.cpp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specification for this function is in [15.1.3.4](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.1.3.4).

---

Modern versions (2018) of V8 implement it in C++.  See [src/uri.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/7.0.99/src/uri.h#34):

```
// ES6 section 18.2.6.5 encodeURIComponenet (uriComponent)
static MaybeHandle<String> EncodeUriComponent(Isolate* isolate,
                                              Handle<String> component) {
```

which calls into `Encode` defined in [uri.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/7.0.99/src/uri.cc#273).

---

Older versions of V8 implemented it in JavaScript and distributed under the BSD license.  See line 359 of [src/uri.js](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/3.26.4/src/uri.js#359).

```
// ECMA-262 - 15.1.3.4
function URIEncodeComponent(component) {
  var unescapePredicate = function(cc) {
    if (isAlphaNumeric(cc)) return true;
    // !
    if (cc == 33) return true;
    // '()*
    if (39 <= cc && cc <= 42) return true;
    // -.
    if (45 <= cc && cc <= 46) return true;
    // _
    if (cc == 95) return true;
    // ~
    if (cc == 126) return true;

    return false;
  };

  var string = ToString(component);
  return Encode(string, unescapePredicate);
}
```

It's not called `encodeURIComponent` there, but this code in the same file, esablishes the mapping:

```
InstallFunctions(global, DONT_ENUM, $Array(
    "escape", URIEscape,
    "unescape", URIUnescape,
    "decodeURI", URIDecode,
    "decodeURIComponent", URIDecodeComponent,
    "encodeURI", URIEncode,
    "encodeURIComponent", URIEncodeComponent
  ));
```

Comment: but you are also calling Encode I just everything plain JavaScript

Comment: Do you have an updated link to the source? I can't find the implementation myself. I'm going to port it to D (language like C++).

Comment: @spikespaz, The code is now native.  See [`uri.h`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/uri.h#34) and [`uri.cc`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/uri.cc#273) in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation:

```
var encodeURIComponent = function( str ) {
    var hexDigits = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var ret = '';
    for( var i=0; i<str.length; i++ ) {
        var c = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if( (c >= 48/*0*/ && c <= 57/*9*/) ||
            (c >= 97/*a*/ && c <= 122/*z*/) ||
            (c >= 65/*A*/ && c <= 90/*Z*/) ||
            c == 45/*-*/ || c == 95/*_*/ || c == 46/*.*/ || c == 33/*!*/ || c == 126/*~*/ ||
            c == 42/***/ || c == 92/*\\*/ || c == 40/*(*/ || c == 41/*)*/ ) {
                ret += str[i];
        }
        else {
            ret += '%';
            ret += hexDigits[ (c & 0xF0) >> 4 ];
            ret += hexDigits[ (c & 0x0F) ];
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What for do you need encodeuricomponent? It is already present in JS.

Anyway, here's an example of implementation:

http://phpjs.org/functions/rawurlencode:501#comment_93984

Comment: Yeah it there in JS but I need open source it part of my project,by the way the you have provided is not working